# exim4 is showing a TLS error on connection... (gnutls_handshake)

Tags: exim, gnutls

My exim server is showing the following error:
 TLS error on connection from xxxx.xxxx.xxxx. ([127.0.0.1]) [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] (gnutls_handshake): A TLS fatal alert has been received.

I'm using the plain authentication and my settings are :

```
plain_server:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = PLAIN
  server_condition = "${if crypteq{$auth3}{${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$auth2}lsearch{CONFDIR/passwd}{$value}{*:*}}}}}{1}{0}}"
  server_set_id = $auth2
  server_prompts = :
  .ifndef AUTH_SERVER_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
     server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$tls_cipher}{}{}{*}}
  .endif
```

Looking forward to any help or pointers

thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone know how to get more detail on that TLS fatal alert, or would I have to run exim under a debugger to get any more detail?

Answer (score 10):

If you are running an exim installation, the reason was GnuTLS here. Solution found at http://blog.josefsson.org/2009/04/16/cacert-and-gnutls/.

Type following commands

1. `apt-get install gnutls-bin` to have `gnutls-cli` available.
2. `gnutls-cli -s -p 25 YOURSMTPHOST` (starts a session with your mailserver)
3. `ehlo foo`
4. `starttls`
5. Press CTRL+d (`^d`)

Then you see something like

`- The hostname in the certificate does NOT match 'example.org'`

Then the subject of your certificate does not match your server `YOURSMTPHOST`.
In my case, I connected to `flupp.de`, but the `CN` of the certificate was `*.flupp.de`. I changed `flupp.de` to `mail.flupp.de` and everyhting worked fine again.

Comment: My certificate was for smtp.domain, but my MX record and the HELO indicated host.domain.  However, after addressing that, I still receive this error in the logs. @koppor

Comment: This might not have helped the original poster, but it did help me. The difference I suppose, is that I'm trying to test STARTTLS on a test server, using the live server's SSL cert. And, well, that just won't work until the test server becomes the live server.

Comment: the commands listed were perfect to verify that this was my problem too, which I suspected. excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess: you've compiled against GnuTLS, the mailserver you're talking to is GMX.de or web.de, and the problem started a few weeks ago? Both these providers turned on TLS in response to the NSA issue, but they didn't quite get it right.

As a workaround, you can compile exim against OpenSSL which is more tolerant, but do note that the problem is with GMX and web.de.

Comment: It started at my server's exim4 installation some days ago. Debian Wheezy. I'm using CACert.org as root CA.

Comment: As I understand it, this causes a slightly different error message and only occurs if you've somehow blocked TLSv1. @koppor

Comment: Yeah, the error message for that is: TLS error on connection from ... (gnutls_handshake): Could not negotiate a supported cipher suite. @koppor

Comment: Ref for above: http://blog.windfluechter.net/comment/3019